# Creating transactions: is it required to send all utxos as inputs and outputs

Tags: transaction

I'm developing some raw tx server-side scripts and dealing with ValueNotConservedUTxO errors. If I create a transaction from a specific address, must I create inputs for all the utxos and then add the ones I'm not sending elsewhere to a change address?

Hopefully I'm just missing a key understanding else I really don't understand why such a waste of blockchain data would be part of the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to create inputs for all utxos at an address; but for every utxo you **do** add as an input, you need to spend it in full *(i.e. including assets that may be included)*, so your outputs and inputs add up correctly *(apart from the transaction fee)*.